# Robot estimated pose

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Usually if we were to set the estimated pose of robot we will just reposition it in rviz by simply clicking to relocate it to our desire position.
What if I wanted to reposition it programatically? (Not a fixed one.)
Or it can be done in terminal?
Because somehow I cant relocate myself in the rviz after I put everything together into my robot. Previously it is able to relocate with only one laser.

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114631/robot-estimated-pose/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is just providing a GUI for publishing a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) to the (per default) "/initialpose" topic. You can just as well publish to that using your own code, [rqt_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_publisher) or [rostopic pub](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_pub) from the command line. If you run rviz and use "2D Pose Estimate" while doing a "rostopic echo /initialpose", you should get something like the following:

```
kohlbrecher@sk-i7:~$ rostopic echo /initialpose
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
      frame_id: world
    pose: 
      pose: 
        position: 
          x: -0.00588150462136
          y: 0.947909832001
          z: 0.0
        orientation: 
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: -0.707230093335
          w: 0.70698344753
      covariance: [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942]
    ---
```

Just use whatever tool suits you best to create such a message and publish to "/intialpose" (provided you didn´t remap/change that topic) and your AMCL node should react accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2014-01-05**:
But the argument will be like ' header.seq header.stamp header.frame_id position.x position.y position.z orientation.x orientation.y orientation.z orientation.w covariance' right?
Anyway I've tried '1 0 map 9.0 -2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.707 0.707 0.25' it says -2 has no such option. I guess my argument wasn't wrong.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-05**:
You need to quote the string such that bash does not interpret the negative sign.

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2014-01-05**:
"1 0 map 9.0 -2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.707 0.707 0.25"
ERROR: Not enough arguments:

- Given: ['1 0 map 9.0 -2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.707 0.707 0.25']
- Expected: ['header', 'pose']

**Comment by [Sahas00](https://answers.ros.org/users/45339/sahas00/) on 2019-09-02**:
Hey there. I know this is not related to the question but could you attach the subscriber you use to get values? I am not able to create one due to multiple errors that I can't really pinpoint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

that's work for me, hope it helps you also

```
{ header: { frame_id: "/map" }, pose: {pose: {position: {x: 0 , y: 0 , z: 0 } , orientation: {x: 0 , y:0 , z:0 ,w:0} } } }
```

---

Originally posted by [bharatdixit16701](https://answers.ros.org/users/49002/bharatdixit16701/) with karma: 11 on 2020-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1